# Flutter pop best practice

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I have the following flow Screen 1 -> Screen 2 -> Dialog (in a separate widget).

Screen 2 displays a dialog (Close? Yes or No). If someone presses Yes, I would like to return to the Screen 1, if they press No, just close the dialog and return to Screen 2. What I currently do  is when Yes is tapped, I do Navigator.pop(context) twice. Is this a good practice? Is there a way to pass the context of Screen 2 to my dialog widget so I can pop that one directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think it would be better to pass the response from the dialog back to the page, and let the page handle the rest.

You can do this:

```
//I'm using a raised button just to call the alert as an example... 
RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Press me'),
    //This part here is the important part
    onPressed: () async {

      //You can return anything when you use Navigator.pop
      //In this case I'm returning a bool indicating if the page should close or not.
      //You have to await this because it depends on user input.
      bool shouldPopResult = await showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          //The content of your dialog

          actions: <Widget>[
            // The value you pass here in Navigator.of(context).pop
            // is the value that will be stored in shouldPopResult,
            // so if "Yes" is pressed, true will return...
            // and if "No", false is returned.
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Yes'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('No'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );

      // This is for if the user dismisses the dialog without pressing a button
      // In that case shouldPopResult would be null, so I'm setting it to false.
      // You can prevent the user from dismissing the dialog
      // setting barrierDismissible to false in the showDialog method.
      if (shouldPopResult == null) shouldPopResult = false;

      // And finally with the dialog already dismissed, you can decide 
      // to go back or not.
      if (shouldPopResult) Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
```

As usual you can extract the dialog as a Widget, or extract the function that handles the dialog response altogether or anything else.

You can see the example of returning data from a page in the flutter documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data).